# SQL Server: verbose error messages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there some configuration option for MS SQL Server which enables more verbose error messages.

Specific example: I would like to see the actual field values of the inserted record which violates a constraint during an insert, to help track down a bug in stored procedures which I haven't been able to reproduce.

Comment: If the issue is occurring from a call to a stored procedure, can't the code that is calling the sp include the fields that were passed to the sp in an error message?

Comment: That is one of the more frustrating things about error messages in sql server. The one you mentioned or the one where data would be truncated. Obviously the engine knows which column(s) were involved. It has been a connect issue for a LONG time and MS has never done anything to fix it.

Comment: @Greylander Please vote up the ["String or binary data would be truncated"](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name) Connect item if you have not already. My favorite Workaround for that item is, "The workaround is to vote above so that MS wakes up and realize the message given is ridiculous."

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any such option.  There are trace flags that give more information about deadlocks, but I've never heard of one that gives more information on a constraint violation.

If you control the application that is causing the crash then extending it's handling (as Jenn suggested) to include parameter values etc.  Once you have the parameter values you can get a copy of live setup on a non-live server and start debugging the issue.

For more options, can any of the users affected reliably reproduce the issue?  If they can then you might be able to run a profiler trace to capture the actual statements / parameter values being sent to the database.  Of course, if you can figure out the steps to reproduce the issue then you can probably use more traditional debugging methods...

You don't say what the constraint is, I'm assuming it is a fairly complex constraint.  If so, could it be broken down into several constraints so you can get more of a hint about the problem with the data?

You could also re-write the constraint as a trigger which could then include more information in the error that it raises.  Although this would obviously need testing before being deployed to a production server!

Personally, I would go with changing the error handling of the application.  It is probably the less risky change.

PS The application that I helped write, and now spend my time supporting, logs quite a lot of data when an unhandled exception occurs.  If it is during a save then our data access layer attaches the complete list of all commands that were being run as part of the save transaction including parameter values.  This has proved to be invaluable on many occasions, including some when tracking down constraint violations.

Comment: Sounds like this is likely all the answer there is, which is mainly "no".  I could add debug logging in the SP, but would prefer to avoid doing that on a production system, hence this question.  I'll leave this open for a while just in case a solution comes along -- but I think most likely I'll be checking this as the answer soon.

Comment: Clearly there is some kind of setting.  On my company's production server, error messages like "SQL error: String or binary data would be truncated in table '[database].dbo.[table]', column '[field]'. Truncated value: '[value]'.
The statement has been terminated." are being generated.  However, trying to reproduce it on a local SQL Server instance, I get a much vaguer message: "SQL error: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."
So there must be a setting somewhere controlling this.

Comment: I found out how to solve my problem: `DBCC TRACEON(460, -1);`  But this is only for the specific error of my last comment.  More info: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7091/verbose-truncation-warnings-sql-insert-statements-sql-server-2019/

Answer (score 2):

In a stored proc, what I do to get better informatino in a complex SP about the errors is take advantage of the fact that table variables are not affected by a rollback. So I put the information I want to use to troubleshoot into table variables at the time I create it and then if I hit the catch block and rollback, after the rollback I insert the data from the table variable into an exception table along with some meta data like the datetime.

With some thought you can design an exception table that will capture what you need from just about any proc (for instance you could concatenate all the input variables into one field, you could put in the step number that failed (of course then you have to assign stepnumbers to a  variable) or you could log every step along the awy and then the last one logged is the one it failed on. Belive me when you are looking at troubleshooting a 100 line SP, this can come in handy. If I have dymanic SQl inteh proc, I can log the SQL variable that contains the dynamic code that was run.

The beauty of this is now you don't have to try to reproduce the error, you know what the input parameters were and any other information you find useful. Yes it can take a bit of time to set up once, but once you do it is relatively easy to get in the habit of putting it into any complex proc that you will want to log errors on.

You might also want to set a an nongeneralized one if you want to return spefic data values of a select used for an insert or the result set of a select that would tell you waht what wopuld have been being updated or deleted.  Then you would have that only if the proc failed. This is a little more work than the general exception table but may be needed in some complex cases.

Comment: Basically the point of the question is whether there is a way to avoid doing this sort of thing.  Annoying to have roll-my-own error reporting for something so obvious.